# Why simple deform not bend in 360

Tags: modifiers

I have add array, solidify and simple deform modifier. I want to make a circle tyre shape but its making some different shape. I want to bend it 360 degree. I twisted with the up and down order but did not work. May i know the reason why its going in different direction. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try to put in a (rotated) empty as origin object for the modifier?

Comment: to make a tire, use a curve(circle) and a curve modifier instead

Comment: @cegaton Yes curve can make curve tire but why simple deform not working i want to know it

Comment: The bend modifier works only on the local x axis. If you use an empty as the  axis, origin for the simple deform modifier, and rotate the empty 90 degrees, you can do what you want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuIyA.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2lTk.png